# Struts 2 - Adding an OptGroup to a <s:select>

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, optgroup, struts-tags

So I have a `<s:select>` tag which is dynamically populated by a returned map of type `List<folder>` from a connected class. I want to add a header (`optgroup`) at two points within the select but can't work out how to build upon the already implemented system.

My select is as follows:

```xml
<s:select id="%{uid}_folder" theme="simple" list="folderList" 
          listKey="id" listValue="title" value="folderId" />
```

So as you can see it is populated by using a map to declare the value and key of the select from the key and value of the map.

The map is created through a long process collecting different values from different tables.

I just want to add two optgroup(s) were appropriate. I have gone down to the map generation and can add info at the appropriate place to add say, `<optgoup>` but the HTML is escaped (which we need)

Please ask if any additional info is required, I am struggling to phrase this question properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a header to the `select` tag you can do it with `headerKey` and `headerValue` attributes.

```
<s:select id="%{uid}_folder" theme="simple" list="folderList" listKey="id"
 listValue="title" value="folderId" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Folder" />
```

The `select` tag doesn't have `optgroup` generated elements.

Comment: Ok, thats good thank you but I need two headers, the list inside the select is split, headers 'shared' 'and personal'

Comment: Then you have to render HTML manually by grouping options in the action or on the client using JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, well I have grouped the options into the appropriate groups, one is returned by thinga() and the other is returned by thingb(). I then add these to a single List<folders> were they then get called by the select. So how would I add a group header to each of the two groups and and then add them together to go into the select? otherwise clientside it is, a little bit of a hack but I guess it will be a loit quicker

Comment: You can update the question with code examples, also let me know where you stuck on.